# Joining two rigid PCBs in a non-flat configuration

Tags: pcb, keyboard, fpc

I would like to design a very minimal split keyboard like the [GergoPlex](https://www.gboards.ca/product/gergoplex) or [Ferris Sweep](https://qweebs.com/shop/keyboards/ferris-sweep/), but my wrists get sore easily with extended pronation and ulnar deviation.

As such, the design I have in mind would have each half almost vertical, in the manner shown in the picture below. It would be held in a similar manner to a vertical mouse.

[image: General shape of keyboard half]

I would like to keep everything fairly rigid, ideally with an adjustable angle and no exposed wires or flexible PCB traces at the join. But as far as I can tell, it can't be done without the risk of exposing the copper if say the wire joining the two gets ripped off the solder joint or the flexible PCB gets damaged.

Pointers and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Surely you don't want these PCBs to be exposed, right? They will have some kind of enclosure. Then it is not clear to me why would you want to connect them (mechanically) at all. Just mount them inside the enclosure and connect with properly routed wires with connectors.

Comment: I guess I just liked the sort of bare minimalist aesthetic of those other keyboards I linked to. You make a fair point though, it would be rather risky to have them not in some kind of enclosure.

Comment: You're going to run into slippage problems if you just have the PCB sitting on their edges like that. Use an enclosure of mount it to a triangular block.

Comment: How about make it a rigid flex board (flex at the apex) and then epoxy it into the angle that you want.  Make a nice big epoxy filet in the acute angle area.  Though, depending on size you may still get PCB flexure when buttons are pressed.  This may or may not be  a problem.

Comment: I had considered a rigid flex board but wasn't sure how viable something like that would be. I might choose a thicker board just to be safe. I think it could work though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use connectors like [these](https://www.mouser.ca/pdfDocs/bwb_rotaconnect_rotatable_btb-2.pdf) ROTACONNECT® connectors:

[image]

The minimum angle of these ones may be insufficiently acute though.

Comment: Maybe leave the apex unconnected and use a pair of those connectors at the base?

Comment: Well the point would be that the apex is where the join is. There is no base. The two boards join only at the apex and nowhere else.

Comment: You could use a FFC connecting the backside of the boards some distance from the apex; 1/3 of the way down, for example.  That way, the boards would protect it.